# What is the difference between these two sentences? - preposition

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

While I watched a compilation video in Youtube, I heard the expression. I'm not a native

speaker, so I want to know the difference of it compared to the other as following.

> 1. A dog is so protective **of** his own owner.
> 2. A dog is so protective **to** his own owner.

Do both have the same meaning? or Are both different?

I believe that both have a different meaning.

Is anyone who explain about it?

Answer (score 0):

> A dog is so protective of his own owner.

From the context, we see that we are referring to a particular dog.  We should hence use the article **the**.

> **The** dog is so protective of his own owner.

I usually use **it/its** to refer to an animal:

> **The** dog is so protective of **its** owner.

*own* is redundant.

Prepositions following *protective* could be either **of** or **towards/toward**, as [shown](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/protective)

> C1
> wanting to protect someone from criticism, hurt, danger, etc. because you like them very much:

> It's easy to be too protective towards/of your children.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=protective+of%2Cprotective+toward%2Cprotective+towards%2Cprotective+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) shows that *of* is the most common.

added after OP's comments

Other than the dictionary I consulted and quoted in my earlier answer, two more dictionary checks also show that the prepositions to use are *of* and *towards*; *to* is not found.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/protective#:%7E:text=If%20someone%20is%20protective%20towards,desire%20to%20keep%20you%20safe.)

> If someone is protective **towards** you, they look after you and show a strong desire to keep you safe.

> He is very protective **towards** his mother. [+ **towards/of**]

[MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/protective)

> He’s very protective **towards** his sister.

> She is fiercely protective **of** her privacy.

As shown in the Ngram results in my earlier answer, the use of **to** had been checked.  Though **to** is shown to have been used, it is not as frequent as **of**.   As I do not have the background of those uses, and with my dictionary checks I would not choose to use that preposition.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Then if the preposition "to" means showing relationship, does it make no sense? I want to know that it is possible to express that way. Is it possible?

Comment: The OP's question is only about changing the preposition. The first half of your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @bak1936, I have added two more dictionary check results and more explanations.

Comment: @Seowjooheng Singapore thanks. I didn't know that other preposition can't be used. I checked there are only two preposition used possibly ; of and toward.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the first one.

protective= wanting to protect someone from harm or danger

I am very protective **of** my brother. He is fiercely protective **of** his children.